# What would be the jquery selection syntax to select an input after a div with some specific text in?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery 1.11 and I want to be able to select an input which is dynamically created with a different id each time.  So I'm thinking I will use some text found in a div just prior to it.

The generated html is something like this:

```
<div>
  <label>
    fixed text
  </label>
</div>
<input ...
```

So I want to select the input just after the div with the text "fixed text" in the label

```
$("inputAfterDivWithLabelWithText=fixed text")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `:contains()` psuedo selector if you are looking to get an element based off of a string. Then the `parent()` method to go up one level, and the `next()` method if your input is the next element in line.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/um3xunnu/1/)

```
$('label:contains("fixed text")').parent().next();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [`next adjacent`](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) selectors:

```js
$(function() {
    var i = $('div:contains(fixed text)+input');
    i.css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    fixed text
  </label>
</div>
<input type="text" value="Highlight me"/>
<div>
  <label>
    other text
  </label>
</div>
<input type="text" value="Ignore me"/>
```

Another option if it is possible for you is just give the `input` a `class` and select that using standard `$('input.someClass')`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can apply some id to your div and use the $.next().

http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
<div id="someid">
  <label>
    fixed text
  </label>
</div>
<input value="aaa"/>

$("#someid").next().val("bbb");
```

Comment: don't have that option, that too is auto generated

Comment: superb - didn't know about contains